# Apps not available for user pages

Tags: 2013, user-profile, sharepoint-addin

our company just started using sharepoint 2013 (in office 365). We are trying to get an app to show up in the user personal pages. In this case it is about the app 'promoted links'.

When we login using an administrator account we can go to our personal site and 'add an app'. We get a list with about 20 possible apps to add to the personal site, including our promoted links app.

When we login as a user we only see the default apps to add, we cannot choose any of the new apps. I tried setting the permissions for an app to allow everyone to access the apps, but still no luck.

We downloaded an app from the store (google maps). All users are able to access that app through their personal site.

Is there anything we need to do for our apps to show up in the personal sites?

Answer (score 0):

Open your mysite page.

Click the settings cog and then click 'manage shared apps'.

Search for the promoted links app and click add.

It should be visible to all users.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-My-Site-host-f7074f0e-7ec8-4380-8d6e-d75b71c55e9c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1